# Not seeing 3.3V between 3.3v Pin and GND

Tags: pi-3

I have a voltmeter set to Volts and I have my red stick on pin 1 and the black stick on the pin 9. I just bought this Raspberry PI, is it broken? My pi is powered on and running rasbian at the moment.

I'm probably going to return this raspberry pi anyways, because it just broke my monitor. Rasbian setup was flickering and now my monitor is burned with the flicker even on my windows OS..

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Could you please specify the pins you've tested according to [established numbering](https://pinout.xyz/)?

Comment: What do you mean by 'pin 9 located between pin 0 and 7'? See pinouts: https://pinout.xyz What power supply are you using?

Comment: My bad, I meant to remove that statement about 0 and 7. The correct pins are pin 1 and 9

Comment: `set to Volts` ... AC or DC? ... `because it just broke my monitor` highly doubtful, perhaps the monitor was faulty to begin with

Comment: What voltage are you getting on your meter? Is it stable? is it *close* to 3.3v? What about the 5v pins?